# Pictures uploaded with valums ajax upload and OctetStreamReader dosn't work in IE - Java/JSP

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, file-upload

I'm having a problem with picture uploading in Internet Explorer 7, 8 and 9 (haven't tested other versions). It works fine in FF and Chrome, but for some reason the picture is uploaded wrong when i try to upload in any versions of IE.

What i mean by that is that the file gets uploaded in the right directory with the right name, but i cant open it in any picture editing programs.

Furthermore when i open the picutre in Notepad++ i see that the picture got some meta data displaying like:

-----------------------------7db1f6c907fe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfile"; filename="jingjang.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

(hashcode here)

-----------------------------7db1f6c907fe--

If i remove the code the picture works fine! So can anyone tell me what is generating the code and how do i stop it? :)

I use Valums Ajax Upload on my JSP page:

```
var imageFolder = "images/upload/<%=user.getUsername()%>/temp/";
new qq.FileUploader({

element: document.getElementById('TempUploadButton'),
action: 'OctetStreamReader',
debug: false,
multiple: false,
params: {"type" : "user"},

onComplete: function(id, fileName) {    
    var d = new Date();
    $("#UserPageAvatarPic a img").attr("src", imageFolder+"<%=user.getUsername()%>.jpg?cache="+d.getTime() );
},
onSubmit : function(id, fileName) {
    // hide all prev elements
    $('#TempUploadButton ul.qq-upload-list li').each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
}

});
```

And OctetStreamReader as my servlet

```
    public class OctetStreamReader extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6748857432950840322L;
private static final String DESTINATION_DIR_PATH = "files";
private static String realPath;
UserService userService = UserService.getService();

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @param config
 * @throws ServletException
 */
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(DESTINATION_DIR_PATH) + "/";
}

/** 
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException {
    User user = userService.getUser(((Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("user")).intValue());
    String type = request.getParameter("type");
    String username = user.getUsername();
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    type = "user";
    try {
        writer = response.getWriter();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log(OctetStreamReader.class.getName() + "has thrown an exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        String filename = "";
        if (type.equals("user")) {
            realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/upload/" + username + "/temp/");
            is = request.getInputStream();
            String strDirectoy = getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/upload/" + username + "/temp/" );
            boolean success = (new File(strDirectoy)).mkdir();
            File f1 = new File(strDirectoy);
            File[] children = f1.listFiles();
            filename = username + ".jpg";
        }
        if (type.equals("post"))  {
            realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/upload/" + username + "/post/");
            is = request.getInputStream();
            String strDirectoy = getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/upload/" + username + "/post/" );
            boolean success = (new File(strDirectoy)).mkdir();
            File f1 = new File(strDirectoy);
            File[] children = f1.listFiles();
            filename = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+".jpg";
        }
        if (type.equals("editpost"))  {
            realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/upload/" + username + "/editpost/");
            is = request.getInputStream();
            String strDirectoy = getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/upload/" + username + "/editpost/" );
            boolean success = (new File(strDirectoy)).mkdir();
            File f1 = new File(strDirectoy);
            File[] children = f1.listFiles();
            filename = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg";
        }


        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(realPath + "/" + filename), false);
        IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
        response.setStatus(response.SC_OK);
        writer.print("{success: true, filename: \"" + filename + "\"}");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        response.setStatus(response.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        writer.print("{success: false}");
        log(OctetStreamReader.class.getName() + "has thrown an exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        response.setStatus(response.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        writer.print("{success: false}");
        log(OctetStreamReader.class.getName() + "has thrown an exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            fos.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }
 writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
}
```

Also in fileuploader.js i tried to change the Content Type from application/octet-stream to multipart/form-data

```
        /**
 * Sends the file identified by id and additional query params to the server
 * @param {Object} params name-value string pairs
 */    
_upload: function(id, params){
    var file = this._files[id],
        name = this.getName(id),
        size = this.getSize(id);

    this._loaded[id] = 0;

    var xhr = this._xhrs[id] = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var self = this;

    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e){
        if (e.lengthComputable){
            self._loaded[id] = e.loaded;
            self._options.onProgress(id, name, e.loaded, e.total);
        }
    };

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){            
        if (xhr.readyState == 4){
            self._onComplete(id, xhr);                    
        }
    };

    // build query string
    params = params || {};
    params['qqfile'] = name;
    var queryString = qq.obj2url(params, this._options.action);

    xhr.open("POST", queryString, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", encodeURIComponent(name));
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    xhr.send(file);
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML file uploads use by default [the `multipart/form-data` request encoding](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2388.html) (this is in order to be able to upload multiple files and/or to mix normal input field values in **one** request). You're however not parsing and extracting the individual form data parts from the request body, instead you're reading and writing the *entire* request body plain unmodified to a file.

```
is = request.getInputStream();
fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(realPath + "/" + filename), false);
IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
```

This is indeed not ever going to work. That you said that it works in FF/Chrome is beyond me. Perhaps you're misinterpreting the results or do not have tested it in those browsers with binary files at all.

You need to use [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) to extract the parts from a `multipart/form-data` request. Or, when you're already on Servlet 3.0, you could also use the Servlet API provided [`HttpServletRequest#getParts()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29) method.

#### See also:

- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)
- [HTML5 File Upload to Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114087/html5-file-upload-to-java-servlet)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you've another problem with the code posted so far. You're storing uploaded files in the web content of the expanded WAR. This is far from a solid permanent storage location. Everytime when you redeploy a new WAR, all those files will get lost. You'd need to backup them everytime which is plain clumsy and error prone. Rather store them in a fixed location outside the expanded WAR folder.

#### See also:

- [Java EE - Best way to get real path to uploaded files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274517/java-ee-best-way-to-get-real-path-to-uploaded-files)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I dont quite understand what you mean by why the way i do it should not work. I got the OctetStreamReader.java from valums homepage together with the whole package and only modified it a little:[link](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)

Also i tried using Apache Commons FileUpload and it worked fine when i submitted the picture together with the form using:

    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />

But it did not work with the Ajax Uploader and i kinda need a dynamic pic upload before submitting the whole form. Thats why i tried to go back to this

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
InputStream is = null;
         // Check that we have a file upload request
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        // Create a factory for disk-based file items
        if (isMultipart) {
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            // Create a new file upload handler
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            try {
                // Parse the request
                ArrayList<DiskFileItem> files = (ArrayList<DiskFileItem>) upload.parseRequest(request);
                if (!files.isEmpty()) {
                    is = files.get(0).getInputStream();
                }
            } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(OctetStreamReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } else {
            is = request.getInputStream();
        }
```